# Alternative to Terrasync for Trimble Windows Mobile unit

Tags: gps, software-recommendations, trimble

I have a number of [Trimble Nomad](http://www.trimble.com/Outdoor-Rugged-Computers/nomad.aspx?dtID=features) 900 series devices and am currently using TerraSync.

TerraSync does the job, but are there any other alternatives out there that would be even simpler to use?

Basically I'm looking for something that's quick and easy to record features and save to a non-post processed file that can be named.  Preferably just a text file with the "average" or best coordinate reading.  The TerraSync workflow (i.e. having to use GPS Pathfinder Office) is overkill for our uses and takes too much time.

Comment: related questions: 

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125120/has-anyone-used-qgis-as-an-alternative-to-terrasync-or-arcgis-mobile/130958#130958

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179150/juno-3d-open-source-software

Answer (score 3):

The Nomad comes with SatViewer which allows you to record up to 64,000 characters of NMEA data per file - NMEA has many different messages defined but all are text, easy to parse, and the GLL message contains lat/long/time etc.

http://www.trimble.com/outdoorrugged/nomad/SatViewerManualrevA.pdf

http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm

Answer (score 2):

A nice cost effective intuitive application called GPSMeter will allow you to 'average a position
http://www.gpsmeter.com/index.php

Good support too from the developer