# Has anyone used QGIS as an alternative to Terrasync or ArcGIS mobile?

Tags: qgis, land-survey, mobile-gis, intramaps-roam

We are planning to purchase a rugged field computer (Trimble, Juniper, Ashtec etc.) for accurately surveying habitats and work sites in remote locations. In the past we have found that the software from ESRI or Trimble will cost nearly as much as the machine. We have occasionally used QGIS in the office on PCs that don't have a licence for our MapInfo GIS (with reasonable results), so I am wondering if anyone has tried using QGIS on any of these professional mobile mapping devices? I can see from online comments that there have been numerous issues with attempts to use QGIS use on tablets, mobiles etc so I am keen to know if there is a device that I can be confident it will work on.

Comment: related questions: 

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14121/alternative-to-terrasync-for-trimble-windows-mobile-unit

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179150/juno-3d-open-source-software

Answer (score 2):

One alternative you could look into is [IntraMaps Roam](https://github.com/DMS-Aus/Roam/releases/tag/v2.3.1) that has been created by Nathan W. It's free and open source which obviously gives it an edge over the ESRI and Trimble and is based on QGIS so you shouldn't have any issues using it.

I have done some basic tests and it's very easy to set up forms and allows you to collect point, line and polygon features - something which is often not available in other free software.

Compared to ArcPad the form builder is really simple to use and quick to set up:

[image]

However, the main issue I have is that I'm yet to find a good combination of hardware to run Roam on. It currently only works on [full windows and not mobile or Android](http://roam-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about/), which limits the choice of devices that can be used, particularly when trying to combine with GPS. (For comparison I currently use Trimble Junos with Windows Mobile running ArcPad).

I would be interested to hear what solution you eventually decide on.