# Juno 3D open source software

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, juno, mobile-gis

Is there an open source software that I can use to collect data with the Juno 3D GPS?

I'm hesitant to buy a Terrasync or ArcPad license.

Comment: This is not for the faint of heart, but you can install Android in a Windows Mobile phone and then you have a lot of options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601675/can-we-install-android-os-on-any-windows-phone-and-vice-versa-and-same-with-iph
One of those options is our open source mobile data collection client which is shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj6OeTZgzM8 A caveat is that although the mobile client is open source, the SaaS service has a free tier, but is not 100% open source.

Comment: related questions:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125120/has-anyone-used-qgis-as-an-alternative-to-terrasync-or-arcgis-mobile/130958#130958

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14121/alternative-to-terrasync-for-trimble-windows-mobile-unit

Answer (score -1):

There is a good OSGeo Wiki [page](https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GIS_Mobile_Comparison) on mobile GIS options describing the functionality of each software. As far as I can tell, [gvSIG Mobile](http://www.gvsig.com:9090/en/products/gvsig-mobile) is well developed for a range of mobile devices, including Windows Mobile versions 5 & 6.

Comment: gvSIG Mobile runs on Juno and software has nice features but latest version is 6 years old http://www.gvsig.com/en/products/gvsig-mobile/downloads. It was hard to find suitable Java for Windows Mobile but perhaps the versions bundled with virtual machine work for you.